# Como manipular uma coluna de arquivo CSV?

Tags: java, arquivo, csv

Oi, gente! Tudo bem?
Estou aprendendo Java e preciso de ajuda com arquivos CSV. Consigo fazer a leitura do arquivo, mas preciso executar operações com algumas colunas. Exemplo, com dados fictícios, da tabela que estou usando:

```
ID, Nome, Idade, Cargo, Salario
15, Alessandro Martins, 25, Assistente Administrativo, 1800
36, Fátima Ribeiro, 30, Gerente Administrativa, 3000
99, Roberta Menezes, 32, Vendedora, 2500
```

A tabela que estou usando tem 17.795 linhas e 185 colunas.

Preciso tirar a média de Idade e definir o maior Salario, mas não sei como percorrer apenas a coluna da Idade ou do Salario, a partir de outros métodos que criei.

Calculará a media de idade:

```
public static double mediaIdade(Como passar a coluna como parâmetro?){
   //Como calcular a média da coluna idade aqui dentro?
   return media;
}
```

Encontrará os 10 maiores salários:

```
public static double dezMaioresSalarios(Como passar a coluna como parâmetro?){
   //Como colocar os 10 maiores salários aqui dentro?
   return media;
}
```

Esse é o código que usei para ler o arquivo:

```
public static BufferedReader lendoCSV(String arquivo, String separador) {
        BufferedReader conteudoArquivo = null;
        String linha = "";

        try{
            conteudoArquivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));
            linha = conteudoArquivo.readLine();
            while((linha = conteudoArquivo.readLine()) != null) {
                jogadores = linha.split(separador);
            }
            System.out.println("A leitura do arquivo deu certo!");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado: \n" + e.getMessage());
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
            System.out.println("Indice fora dos limites: \n" + e.getMessage());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de entrada de dados: \n" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(conteudoArquivo != null) {
                try {
                    conteudoArquivo.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Erro de entrada de dados: \n" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return conteudoArquivo;
    }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já, muito obrigada!

Comment: Me parece que depois que tu deu o `split` na linha é só acessar os elementos do array. Como é um CSV a coluna vai ser sempre a mesma. Ex.: `jogadores[2]` sempre vai conter a idade.

Comment: Sim. O problema é como faço para somar toda a coluna idade e tirar a média? Como percorro essa coluna para pegar dados que eu quero? Exemplo: a coluna idade(jogadores[2]) tem 17.995 linhas, como faço para somar todas essa idades de tirar a média, se todo as idades estão numa única entrada de um vetor e não em um vetor inteiro... Além disso, como vou converter cada linha, dessa coluna em um tipo double?

Comment: Dentro do while...
Cada iteração dele é uma linha que está sendo lida. Basta ter uma variável externa para guardar a soma e outra para guardar a quantidade de items.
Assim ao sair do for, todas as linhas terão sido lidas e é só fazer o cálculo da média.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz tempo que não programo em Java mas acho que dá pra entender o conceito.

Dentro do while, onde são lidas cada linha do CSV, serão feitas as conversões e somadas a um acumulador.
No fim é calculada a média.

```java
conteudoArquivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));

double soma_idade = 0;
int qtde = 0;

String linha = conteudoArquivo.readLine();
while((linha = conteudoArquivo.readLine()) != null) {
    jogador = linha.split(separador);
    soma_idade += Float.parseFloat(jogador[2]);
    qtde++;
}
double media_idade = soma_idade / qtde;
System.out.println("A leitura do arquivo deu certo!");
```

Comment: Que legal! Obrigada! Enquanto estava pensando em como deixar minha pergunta mais clara, tive uma ideia e funcionou e ela parecida com a sua. Só que optei por jogar todos os valores convertidos em um outro vetor, que chamei de idade, agora deu certo! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, você cria uma classe para representar o jogador:

```
public class Jogador {
    private final int id;
    private final String nome;
    private final int idade;
    private final String cargo;
    private final int salario;

    public Jogador(int id, String nome, int idade, String cargo, int salario) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.cargo = cargo;
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public static Jogador parse(String linha, String separador) {
        String[] partes = linha.split(separador);
        if (partes.length != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Linha de jogador mal-formada: " + linha);
        }
        try {
            return new Jogador(
                Integer.parseInt(partes[0].trim()),
                partes[1].trim(),
                Integer.parseInt(partes[2].trim()),
                partes[3].trim(),
                Integer.parseInt(partes[4].trim()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Linha de jogador mal-formada: " + linha);
        }
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public int getIdade() { return idade; }
    public String getCargo() { return cargo; }
    public int getSalario() { return salario; }
}
```

Observe o método `parse` que serve para transformar uma linha do CSV em uma instância do jogador.

Para ler todas as linhas do arquivo, você pode usar o [método `Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)):

```
Files.readAllLines(new File(arquivo).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Isso daí te fornecerá uma `List<String>` com o conteúdo de todas as linhas do arquivo. Isso também elimina a necessidade de abrir e fechar o arquivo, e ler cada uma das linhas.

E para converter essas linhas em jogadores, pode usar o [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
public static List<Jogador> lerJogadores(String arquivo, String separador) throws IOException {
    return Files
            .readAllLines(new File(arquivo).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .stream()
            .skip(1)
            .map(s -> Jogador.parse(s, separador))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Observe o `.skip(1)`, que serve para pular o cabeçalho do CSV. O resultado é uma `List<Jogador>`.

Para calcular a média de vários jogadores, pode usar o [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), que já tem o [método `average()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average()) que serve exatamente para calcular a média:

```
public static double mediaIdade(List<Jogador> jogadores) {
    return jogadores.stream().mapToInt(Jogador::getIdade).average().orElse(0.0);
}
```

E para os 10 maiores salários:

```
public static int[] dezMaioresSalarios(List<Jogador> jogadores) {
    return jogadores.stream().mapToInt(Jogador::getSalario).map(x -> -x).sorted().limit(10).map(x -> -x).toArray();
}
```

Aqui há um truquezinho. O [método `sorted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()) ordena o `IntStream`, mas isso pegaria os 10 menores salários ao invés dos 10 maiores. A solução é colocar um `.map(x -> -x)` antes e um depois do `.sorted()` para forçar ele a ordenar de trás-para-frente. O `limit(10)` garante que você vai pegar só os 10 que importam.

Depois disso, é fácil fazer o `main`. Note o [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Jogador> jogadores = lerJogadores("xxx.csv", ",");
    System.out.println("Média de idade: " + mediaIdade(jogadores));
    System.out.println("10 maiores salários: " + Arrays.toString(dezMaioresSalarios(jogadores)));
}
```

Aqui segue o código completo:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Jogador> jogadores = lerJogadores("xxx.csv", ",");
        System.out.println("Média de idade: " + mediaIdade(jogadores));
        System.out.println("10 maiores salários: " + Arrays.toString(dezMaioresSalarios(jogadores)));
    }

    public static List<Jogador> lerJogadores(String arquivo, String separador) throws IOException {
        return Files
                .readAllLines(new File(arquivo).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .stream()
                .skip(1)
                .map(s -> Jogador.parse(s, separador))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static double mediaIdade(List<Jogador> jogadores) {
        return jogadores.stream().mapToInt(Jogador::getIdade).average().orElse(0.0);
    }

    public static int[] dezMaioresSalarios(List<Jogador> jogadores) {
        return jogadores.stream().mapToInt(Jogador::getSalario).map(x -> -x).sorted().limit(10).map(x -> -x).toArray();
    }

    public static class Jogador {
        private final int id;
        private final String nome;
        private final int idade;
        private final String cargo;
        private final int salario;

        public Jogador(int id, String nome, int idade, String cargo, int salario) {
            this.id = id;
            this.nome = nome;
            this.idade = idade;
            this.cargo = cargo;
            this.salario = salario;
        }

        public static Jogador parse(String linha, String separador) {
            String[] partes = linha.split(separador);
            if (partes.length != 5) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Linha de jogador mal-formada: " + linha);
            }
            try {
                return new Jogador(
                    Integer.parseInt(partes[0].trim()),
                    partes[1].trim(),
                    Integer.parseInt(partes[2].trim()),
                    partes[3].trim(),
                    Integer.parseInt(partes[4].trim()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Linha de jogador mal-formada: " + linha);
            }
        }

        public int getId() { return id; }
        public String getNome() { return nome; }
        public int getIdade() { return idade; }
        public String getCargo() { return cargo; }
        public int getSalario() { return salario; }
    }
}
```